# How do I render section headers with ListView in react native?

Tags: react-native

I'm looking at the documentation and see that I need to implement  `renderSectionHeader` but what else do I need to implement and how do I prepare the data to encode the section information?  I don't see anything in the facebook documentation that explains that and I'm getting an error `_this.getSectionId is not a function`

```
  ...
  renderSectionHeader = (sectionData, sectionID) => {
    return (
      <Divider styleName="section-header">
        <Caption>DO SOMETHING WITH sectionData?</Caption>
      </Divider>
    );
  };
  ...
        <ListView
          data = { results }
          autoHideHeader = { true }
          loading = { isLoading }
          renderHeader = { this.renderHeader }
          onRefresh = { data.refetch }
          renderSectionHeader={ this.renderSectionHeader }
          renderRow={ this.renderRow }
        />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Working Example

Here's a working sample that I've modified from [this excellent post](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/1706).

First of all, your `dataBlob`:

```js
var dataBlob = {
  'sectionID1' : { name: 'section1' },
  'sectionID1:rowID1' : { name: 'section1row1' },
  'sectionID1:rowID2' : { name: 'section1row2' },
  'sectionID2' : { name: 'section2' },
  'sectionID2:rowID1' : { name: 'section2row1' },
  'sectionID2:rowID2' : { name: 'section2row2' },
}
```

Whatever data that you have will have to be manipulated. It doesn't have to look exactly like this but for this example, this is what we're going to tell the `ListView` to expect.

Now we need to tell `ListView` how to extract the sections and the rows from this dataBlob.

```js
var getSectionData = (dataBlob, sectionID) => {
  return dataBlob[sectionID];
}

var getRowData = (dataBlob, sectionID, rowID) => {
  return dataBlob[sectionID + ':' + rowID];
}
```

You can tell by the two methods above that you can have a different structure to your `dataBlob`, you just need to update these two methods to let it know how to access it.

Now we'll create a dataSource that uses sections.

```js
this.ds = new ListView.DataSource({
  getSectionData: getSectionData,
  getRowData: getRowData,
  rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2,
  sectionHeaderHasChanged: (s1, s2) => s1 !== s2
})
```

This part seems redundant to me but is required. You have to list out the section ids and the row ids in separate arrays.

```js
var sectionIDs = [ 'sectionID1', 'sectionID2' ];

var rowIDs = [ [ 'rowID1', 'rowID2' ], [ 'rowID1', 'rowID2' ] ];
```

Now you need to update the state with the dataSource:

```js
this.state = {
  dataSource: this.ds.cloneWithRowsAndSections( dataBlob, sectionIDs, rowIDs )
}
```

And, finally, you need to display it in your ListView.

```js
<ListView
  dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
  renderRow={(rowData, sectionID, rowID) => {
    return <Text>{rowData.name}</Text>
  }} 
  renderSectionHeader={ (sectionData, sectionID) => {
    return <Text>{sectionData.name}</Text>
  }}
/>
```

That'll get you started. I hope that helps.

Comment: As a side note, I switched to `SectionList` and it is much easier to use. It's more performant than `ListView` because it makes use of `FlatList`, which doesn't use `dataSource`. I'm not sure when you want to use `ListView` versus `SectionList` but if you can get away with `SectionList`, I'd highly recommend it.

Answer (score 1):

Section headers require a bit more work, but I'll try to cover everything:

```
// This is how your datasource should look
const ds = new ListView.DataSource({
  rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2,
  sectionHeaderHasChanged : (s1, s2) => s1 !== s2,
  getSectionData: (dataBlob, sectionId) => dataBlob[sectionId];,
  getRowData: (dataBlob, sectionId, rowId) => dataBlob[rowId],
});
// This is your state
this.state = {
  dataSource: ds.cloneWithRowsAndSections(dataBlob, sectionIds, rowIds),
}; // sectionsIds and rowIds should be values in your dataBlob so RN knows what belongs in which section

// And this will be your listview
<ListView
    style={styles.container}
    dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
    renderRow={(data) => <Row {...data} />}
    renderSeparator={(sectionId, rowId) => <View key={rowId} style={styles.separator} />}
    renderSectionHeader={(sectionData) => <SectionHeader {...sectionData} />}
  />
```

Not sure if the made changes to the listview since this was made but hopefully it will help you head in the right direction on how it's supposed to be set up.